return some rows if condition is met else return different rows if another condition met
I have 3 tables A,B and C.
Table A(id int,rl_id int) PK is id.



id
rl_id




1
3


2
3


3
4



Table B(rl_id,rl_nm,o_id,o_nm) PK rl_id



rl_id
rl_nm
o_id
o_nm




4
a
0
dev


5
b
0
subp


6
c
52
subp



Table C(c_id,rl_nm)



c_id
rl_nm




52
subp


61
dev



I am applying a join between A,B and C
select B.rl_id,C.rl_nm,B.rl_nm,B.o_id,C.c_id 
from A 
inner join B on A.rl_id=B.rl_id
inner join C 
    on C.rl_nm=B.o_nm and 
        A.rl_id=case when C.c_id=B.o_id 
                then B.rl_id
                else (case when B.o_id=0 then B.rl_id)
                end 
group by B.rl_id;

the problem is:
If c_id from table C matches with o_id from Table B along with rl_nm (table C) with o_nm(table B) then rl_id of that record from table B should come as output.
For example: 52 c_id is matching then I should get rl_id as 6
And if there is no match then based on rl_nm(table C) whatever row matches in Table B, that role id will be returned.
select B.rl_id,C.rl_nm,B.rl_nm,B.o_id,C.c_id 
from A 
inner join B on A.rl_id=B.rl_id
inner join C 
    on C.rl_nm=B.o_nm and 
        A.rl_id=case when C.c_id=B.o_id 
                    then B.rl_id
                    else (case when B.o_id=0 then B.rl_id)
                end 
group by B.rl_id;

expected output :



B.rl_id
C.rl_nm
B.rl_nm
B.o_id
C.c_id`




4
dev
dev
61
0


6
subp
subp
52
52



If Table C data is like this:



c_id
rl_nm




304
subp


304
dev



then expected output :



B.rl_id
C.rl_nm
B.rl_nm
B.o_id
C.c_id`




4
dev
dev
304
0


5
subp
subp
304
0



select B.rl_id,C.rl_nm,B.rl_nm,B.o_id,C.c_id 
from A 
inner join B on A.rl_id=B.rl_id
inner join C 
    on C.rl_nm=B.o_nm and 
        A.rl_id=case when C.c_id=B.o_id 
                    then B.rl_id
                    else (case when B.o_id=0 then B.rl_id)
                end 
group by B.rl_id;


Please cleanup your question so that we can properly read it.

Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY server SQL mode then fix your queries incorrectness.

If ... matches ... then ... if there is no match then ... It is possible that both matched and non-matched rows conbinations exists. So you must prioritize the combined output rows. Use either CTE with according ROW_NUMBER and final WHERE rn=1 or two separate subqueries with NOT EXIST in 2nd subquery.

There's no need to use nested CASE in the ELSE clauses. You can have multiple WHEN conditions and it uses the first one. You're also missing END for the inner CASE.

I'm having trouble understanding what you're doing, but I think this is usually done using LEFT JOIN and then using COALESCE() or IFNULL() to return the default value from one table if there's no match in the other table.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046859/left-join-with-default-relation for example

Perhaps, you should properly join 3 tables and then take values in SELECT clause by your rules.

@Akina :yes both combination can co exist simultaneously.
